# Creating shape with CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

Trying to create this shape with css

[image]

I've managed to get to this result

[image]

but can't figure out how to create the arc in the bottom part of the rectangle
this is my css

```
.left-page {             
         color: hsl(35, 35, 35);
         border-top-left-radius:  26px;
         border-bottom-left-radius:  26px;
         border: solid 1px hsl(274,65,35);
         
    }
```

Comment: would it be easier to just use an image and set it as the background? if not, one thing you can do is add a ::before or ::after selector (or actual element) that's position absolute, and round it, but that's gonna be a real headache

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this but i dont think this is a great idea:

```css
.shape {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
 
}

.shape::after {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bottom 'footer' (or `after` pseudo element) to illustrate the effect you're looking for.

```css
.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  
  border: 1px solid purple;
  border-bottom: none;
  
  border-top-left-radius: 32px;
}

.bottom {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  
  border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
  border-left: 1px solid purple;
  border-right: 1px solid purple;
  
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```